# Change SequenceEncoder FPS

Tags: java, android, bitmap, encoder

I have a set of images and I would like to generate a MP4 video from it.
I am using `jcodec - SequenceEncoder`, but the photos go too fast, there is any way to change the FPS?

My code:

```
public void generateVideo(ArrayList<Uri> Uris) {
    try {
        File file = this.GetSDPathToFile("", "test.mp4"); //just normal path..
        SequenceEncoder encoder = new SequenceEncoder(file);

        for (Uri photo : Uris) {
            // getting bitmap from drawable path
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), photo);
            Picture pic = this.fromBitmap(bitmap);
            encoder.encodeNativeFrame(pic); //*too fast!*

        }
        encoder.finish();
        Toast.makeText(this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I thought about adding more `encoder.encodeNativeFrame(pic)`, it working but takes too much time... :

```
dependencies {
   ....
    compile 'org.jcodec:jcodec-android:0.1.9'
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any idea? Need it too..

Comment: Have you find your solution , I am also stuck by this.